# How to use Hibernate with MSSQL Synonym in Java Standalone

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, synonym

hej,

is there any way to bind hibernate - i use 4.3.11 - to MSSQL Servers Synonyms in standard java standalone application?
(i read that it should be possible but i haven't found the way..)

Thank You.
nebod